# Alter a variable inside a function from another function

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I change value of a variable inside the first function, from within the second function?

This is what I have came up with so far.
I am trying to add or subtract 1 from:
self.num = 0

But it doesn't add or subtract.

```
from tkinter import *


class Application():
    def __init__(self, master):
        print("Initialization")

        self.frame = Frame(master, width=800, height=600)
        self.frame.pack()

        # I want to initialize self.num as 0
        self.num = 0

        # Call calc funtion
        self.calc()

    def calc(self):
        # Subtract number
        self.subButton = Button(self.frame, text="-", command=self.subNum)
        self.subButton.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # Add number
        self.addButton = Button(self.frame, text="+", command=self.addNum)
        self.addButton.grid(row=0, column=2)

        # Display the number
        self.numText = Label(self.frame, text=self.num)
        self.numText.grid(row=0, column=1)

        # Break mainloop. Quit Program
        self.quitButton = Button(self.frame, text="Quit", command=self.frame.quit)
        self.quitButton.grid(row=3, column=0)

    # Here I add 1 to self.num
    def addNum(self):
        self.num += 1
        print("Add")
    # Here I subtract 1 from self.num
    def subNum(self):
        self.num -= 1
        print("Subtract")


root = Tk()
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are changing the value of `self.num` but you are not changing the text of your label.

You can either use `IntVar` and see it change automatically or you can change it manually yourself. Personally I'd prefer `IntVar` in this case.

```
class Application():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.num = IntVar(value=0)

    def calc(self):
        ....
        self.numText = Label(self.frame, textvariable=self.num) 
        #use textvariable instead of text option

    def addNum(self):
        #to change value, you should use set/get methods of IntVar
        self.num.set(self.num.get() + 1)
```

If you don't want to use `IntVar()`, you can use

```
def addNum(self):
    self.num += 1
    self.numText["text"] = self.num 
    #or
    #self.numText.config(text=self.num)
    print("Add")
```

Comment: This works perfectly :) 
I tried both methods and I prefer not using IntVar because it looks less "messy".

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Label doesn't change, not the variable. If you want to update your label, you need to use a `textvariable` property and initialize a tkinter's `IntVar` in your class. Here's how it can be done:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    print("Initialization")

    self.frame = Frame(master, width=800, height=600)
    self.frame.pack()

    # I want to initialize self.num as 0
    self.num = IntVar()

    # Call calc funtion
    self.calc()
```

Notice the declaration of `self.num`.

Next, here's how the label should be declared:

```
    self.numText = Label(self.frame, textvariable=self.num)
    self.numText.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

Now, to modify an `IntVar`, you should use its `get()` and `set()` methods, as you cannot simply assign value to it:

```
# Here I add 1 to self.num
def addNum(self):
    self.num.set(self.num.get() + 1)
    print("Add")
# Here I subtract 1 from self.num
def subNum(self):
    self.num.set(self.num.get() - 1)
    print("Subtract")
```

You can read up more on tkinter's variable classes [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm).